# Regex to split closing bracket followed by space alongside "\b"

Tags: c#, regex

Using C# I'm breaking strings like this into tokens:

```
Sum(Table.Fieldname) As Alias
Table2.Fieldname2 As Alias
```

I'm breaking it out as:

```
var c = "Sum(Table.Fieldname) As Alias";

string[] Tokens = Regex.Split(c, @"\b")
```

\b nicely gave me all the tokens but the problem is I need to regard a closing bracket followed by a space as separate tokens, at the moment they are in the same element:

```
?System.text.RegularExpressions.Regex.split("Sum(Table.Fieldname) As Alias", "\b")
{Length=11}
(0): ""
(1): "Sum"
(2): "("
(3): "Table"
(4): "."
(5): "Fieldname"
(6): ") "
(7): "As"
(8): " "
(9): "Alias"
(10): ""
```

In the above I need element 6 to become elements 6 and 7 with the brackets separate from spaces. How can I modify the regex to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay with ignoring empty matches, instead of `Regex.Split()`, you may use `Regex.Matches()` with the following pattern:

```
\w+?(?=\W|$)|\W
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4nYmVI/1)**.

**C# example:**

```
string s = "Sum(Table.Fieldname) As Alias";
string[] tokens = Regex.Matches(s,@"\w+?(?=\W|$)|\W")
                       .OfType<Match>()
                       .Select(m => m.Value)
                       .ToArray();
foreach (string token in tokens)
    Console.WriteLine($"'{token}'");
```

**Output:**

```
'Sum'
'('
'Table'
'.'
'Fieldname'
')'
' '
'As'
' '
'Alias'
```

---

If you want to stick with `Regex.Split()`, you can do the same thing using something like this:

```
(?<=\w)(?=\W)|(?<=\W)(?=.)
```

See a live C# example comparing both methods here: https://rextester.com/MYF52225

Comment: Thanks, I was just getting going with this but it wasn't preserving the separators. The accepted answer allowed me to continue with split and seems to work perfectly

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "not preserving the separators". Does this not produce the output you expect? Glad you got the answer you wanted though :)

Comment: @user2728841 Note that the accepted answer will still treat things like `)*` as one token. Not sure if that's actually the behavior you expect.

Comment: Yes I'll need it to work for Sum(Category.CategoryName) As Fred, Count(*) As Bert

Comment: So I need it to consider that asterisk is a separate item

Comment: @user2728841 Well, that's what I thought at first. That's why my pattern treats _any non-word character_ as a separate token. See here: https://regex101.com/r/4nYmVI/2

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

```
\b|(?<=\s)(?=\W)|(?<=\W)(?=\s)
```

Kind of a user defined boundary anchor :) Zero length, matching between space and non word characters.

`(?<=\s)(?=\W)` matches the position between a space and a non-word character.
`(?<=\W)(?=\s)` the other way around.

[See it here at regexstorm.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%7C%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cs%29%28%3F%3D%5CW%29%7C%28%3F%3C%3D%5CW%29%28%3F%3D%5Cs%29&i=Sum%28Table.Fieldname%29%20As%20Alias)

---

**Edit**

*Guessing* that your additional request means that you want to split different non word characters **except** for spaces, this could do it for you:

```
\b|(?<=\s)(?=[^\w\s])|(?<=[^\w\s])(?=\s)|(?<=[^\w\s])(?=[^\w\s])
```

It uses the character class `[^\w\s]` to represent *non words*, thus not matching spaces. And adding the alternation that matches the position between two of this character class splits there as well.

[Here at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%5cs%29%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%5cw%5cs%5d%29%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%5b%5e%5cw%5cs%5d%29%28%3f%3d%5cs%29%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%5b%5e%5cw%5cs%5d%29%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%5cw%5cs%5d%29&i=Sum%28Table.Fieldname%29+As+Alias+++++++Count%28*%29)

Comment: Any way of improving this so it works with Count(*) ? i.e. ( , * and ) would all be separate elements ?

Comment: Didn't the edit work, or is it that you **do** want multiple spaces as separate items?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split on non-word characters `\W`, see a matching [demo](https://regex101.com/r/57dM2l/2/)

Comment: That unfortunately wouldn't work with a simple Regex.Split, as it would "swallow"  the non-word characters such as the dot and the parantheses :-(

Comment: Yes I'm hoping to keep the separators